# My inputs of type="submit" are all textbox

Tags: php, html, ldap

**Edit** To save you some time, the issue was a typo. I wrote `sumbit` instead of `submit` and got stuck on it a few hours. That's all.

I just ran into something strange with HTML. I know I surely did a stupid mistake but I can't find it. I don't perfectly remember HTML but it seems all fine to me.

Here's the page :

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="post">
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <th>Prénom</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Adresse e-mail</th>
                <th>N° de téléphone</th>
                <th>Modifier</th>
            </tr>

            <?php 

                for($x=0; $x<count($ad_users); $x++)
                {
                    if (!empty($ad_users[$x]))
                    {
                        echo '<tr><td>'. $ad_users[$x]['first_name'] .'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $ad_users[$x]['last_name'] .'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $ad_users[$x]['email'] .'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $ad_users[$x]['telephonenumber'] .'</td>';
                        echo '<td> <input type="sumbit" name="'.$ad_users[$x]['accountname'].'" value="Modifier"> </td></tr>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelling mistake: change  type="sumbit" to type="submit"

Comment: Oh well, as I said I feel really stupid now x)
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You should spell `submit` with the `b` before the `m`.

Unrecognised values (like `sumbit`) default to `text`.